# Conditional RegExp Replace - if reference is found, then write something else

Tags: regex, replace, conditional-statements, sublimetext

#### Two cases

```
1. Key<A, M> desc = newKey();
2. Property<B, N> type = newKey("type", B.bar);
```

#### The RegExp and replace

```
find: (?:Key|Property)<(.*), (.*)> (.*) = newKey\((.*)\);
rep.: Foo<C$1, $2> $3 = pl.nP("$3", $2.class); // ($4)
```

#### The Result

```
1. Foo<CA, M> desc = pl.nP("desc", M.class); //
2. Foo<CB, N> type = pl.nP("type", N.class); // ("type", B.bar)
```

### The Problem:

Now I want to avoid the empty comment at the line 1.

> **Is there a way to write the $4 and the stuff around it only if $4
>   isn't empty?**

Comment: You could use the following regex replacement in Notepad++: `(?:Key|Property)<(.*), (.*)> (.*) = newKey\((.+)?\);` => `Foo<C$1, $2> $3 = pl.nP("$3", $2.class);(?4 // $4:)`.

Answer (score 1):

You could remove empty comments afterwards with another regular expression.

**EDIT**

Another solution would be to deal with the special case separately (`... = newKey\(\)`).
Perhaps you could automate this process with a simple script, if the tedium of repetitive typing becomes too great
(eg. when dealing with multiple conditionals).

As far as I know, there isn't any 'intelligence' built into the replace field in Sublime Text; all you can do is to *assemble* the captured pieces to your liking.

While skimming through a few Google search results yesterday, I found an article about conditional *patterns* in Perl, but nothing pertaining to the problem at hand.

For the sake of full disclosure, I should say that I am in no sense an expert in the field, so I could be wrong. I do however have some experience with the Python API for
Sublime Text. It might be possible to implement this functionality yourself, if it doesn't already exist within the plethora of extensions available.

I'm sorry if this sounds like a very long-winded 'uh uh', but I'll be on the lookout for a general solution.

Comment: That's true and that does solve this particular scenario, however it does not answer the core of the question. If you are sure the solution doesn't exist, type it in your answer, together with your suggestion and I will accept it :). A `no go` is also an acceptable answer..